# Date with time in JSON_TABLE doesn't save time

Tags: sql, json, oracle, datetime, oracle12c

I have this code which given the a JSON array inserts it in a table:

```sql
INSERT INTO log (
   "uuid",
   "date",
   "msg",
   "level"
)
   WITH t ( log ) AS (
      SELECT
         JSON_QUERY('[{"uuid": "20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "date": "2021-10-18T13:49:15+01:00", "msg":"aaaa", "level": "debug" },
                  {"uuid": "20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "date": "2021-10-18T13:49:15+01:00", "msg":"bbbb", "level": "debug" }]'
         , '$')
      FROM
         dual
   )
   SELECT
      "uuid",
      "date",
      "msg",
      "level"
   FROM
      t
      CROSS JOIN
         JSON_TABLE ( log, '$'
            COLUMNS (
               NESTED PATH '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                     "uuid" VARCHAR2 ( 36 ) PATH '$.uuid',
                     "date" DATE PATH '$.date',
                     "msg" VARCHAR2 ( 1024 ) PATH '$.msg',
                     "level" VARCHAR2 ( 5 ) PATH '$.level'
                  )
            )
         )
```

This is only saving the date (2021-10-18) into the database, but not the time. How can I save date and time?

Comment: dates are stored as packets of bits. The time is always stored, but you have to use the right `nls_date_format` to show it.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez While true, that is not happening here [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=23deb62f8da409c72f79254742334f64).

Comment: @RobertoHernandez @MTO solution worked for me, weird that it works with `timestamp` but not with `date` since date supports time too!

Comment: @user5507535, I post a solution with `date` that it works for me

Comment: @MTO, I post a solution for `date` columns, although I think yours with timestamp is cleaner.

Comment: Data type conflict: JSON does not have a DATE data type, but the general consensus is to represent dates as strings in the ISO format, which **does not include time-of-day**. Oracle, of course, includes time-of-day in dates; but in the JSON implementation they follow the common usage of only using the ISO format. But aside from that, your own inputs have time zone component, which is only possible for timestamps anyway. Why are you saving that data as `date`, and not as `timestamp with time zone`? That is likely to cause you problems later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

```sql
INSERT INTO log ( "uuid", "date", "msg", "level" )
  WITH t ( log ) AS (
    SELECT JSON_QUERY(
             '[{"uuid": "20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "date": "2021-10-18T13:49:15+01:00", "msg":"aaaa", "level": "debug" },
             {"uuid": "20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "date": "2021-10-18T13:49:15+01:00", "msg":"bbbb", "level": "debug" }]',
             '$'
           )
    FROM   dual
  )
  SELECT "uuid",
         "date" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
         "msg",
         "level"
  FROM   t
         CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
           log,
           '$[*]'
           COLUMNS (
             "uuid" VARCHAR2 ( 36 ) PATH '$.uuid',
             "date" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE PATH '$.date',
             "msg" VARCHAR2 ( 1024 ) PATH '$.msg',
             "level" VARCHAR2 ( 5 ) PATH '$.level'
           )
         )
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=119416ac06fd7276e2a2ca7304126df6)*